# Google sheet multi list attendance - optimal solution?

Tags: google-sheets, time-and-attendance

I am trying to make one sheet with multiple lists for attendance tracking. Each list has a specific task/group like so:

**Master list:** all members with their contact info and attendance scores for each month and each class in which they participate (example: present 3 out of 10 times).

**Class 1:** all members from *master list,* that are enrolled in *class 1* show up here. Each member can be marked with a tick box if present for every date (all dates set in advance). Each date can be "turned off" with a tick box if class is cancelled. At the end of the month there is a counter for how many times a person was present out of all classes (if class was cancelled with a previously mentioned tick it subtracts that class from total class counter for that month). Attendance data gets sent into *master list,* where you can see monthly attendance for each participant.

**Class 2:** same as *class 1,* with different people attending it.

**Class 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8:** same as *class 2.*

There are about **300 people** in *master list.* What I have tried is to have a check box in master list that puts people in all classes they attend (*FILTER function*). Then I do attendance math in class 1 and send data to master list with *VLOOKUP function.* I have added pictures of what I currently have at the end of the post.

**My question is,** if there is any way to optimise this sheet? It is supposed to be ran on a phone/tablet since I can not have a designated PC in the gym. And since there are usually around 50 participants in a class I need to be able to tick them quickly without switching lists. My current sheet is running very poorly on my tablet (Samsung galaxy tab S6 lite) and therefore I am searching for more optimal way of doing this. Since filter function looks trough the whole master list it probably takes up a lot of time to process. And the required processing power is even greater since I have 8 different classes. This is supposed to be all done in one document so it is easy to add students to any class and to have information about attendance for all classes in one place so we can charge them accordingly. Splitting all classes into different documents and then have all the data sent back to the *master list* would also be acceptable, if it is possible. Finally, I use Google sheets instead of Excel because it is cloud based and free, so all other coaches can access it too. I would be interested about hearing Excel solutions, if all said requirements can be met.

[Master list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2Twv.png),
[Class 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sePa3.png), (All other classes same as *Class 1,* with different members and some with different dates.)

Comment: Stack is a free forum run on the donated time of volunteer contributors. As such, it is designed to share knowledge or a "nudge in the right direction" with people who have already invested their own time in adequate research and learning, and who have largely already solved their own issue but have gotten stuck in some small facet of their own solution. It is not a place where people can come to get customized, time-intensive, client-level solutions at no cost. (No such place exists.) There are many resources online for posting jobs and hiring a developer to build such solutions.

Comment: I am asking for a nudge in the right direction like using a "better function" or another perspective for my problem. I do not expect anyone to do the whole thing instead of me but I am quite sure there is a better way of doing this just by doing some small tweaks to the sheet

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.